# Sort a sum of products in sympy output

Tags: sorting, variables, sympy

I try to find a pattern using simpy.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import simplify

b = symbols('b:100')
a = symbols('a:100')


A = Matrix([[1, 0],[0, 1]])
for i in [10,9,8]:
        A = A @ Matrix([[1+b[i]-a[i] , -b[i]],[1, 0]])

print(expand(simplify(A[0,0])))
```

The output is

```
-a10*a8*a9 + a10*a8*b9 + a10*a8 + a10*a9*b8 + a10*a9 - a10*b8*b9 - a10*b8 - a10 + a8*a9*b10 + a8*a9 - a8*b10*b9 - a8*b9 - a8 - a9*b10*b8 - a9*b10 - a9*b8 - a9 + b10*b8*b9 + b8*b9 + b8 + 1
```

Is there any way to sort the summands in a more usefull way? Like show first all summands with containing 3 characters and then summands with only 2 ... and also sort the products in the summands so that a comes before b and a10 before a9 before a8 and so on?

theres a command "sorted" in the simpy bib but i need list elements for this command. Any other nice suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: `import sympy;
from sympy import *;
from sympy import simplify` Those three lines are redundant. Also, I strongly, very strongly encourage you never to use `from sympy import *`.

Comment: and why? What else should i use to calculate with variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own key when sorting. Does this do what you want?

[image]